# How do I sort by datetype using SearchQuery/full text search in Couchbase?

Tags: couchbase, spring-data-couchbase, couchbase-java-api

I have configured and indexed receivedDate. It looks like receivedDate:"2019-02-130 01:01:01 PM" in my database. How do I sort using date type text or date type instance?

Here are configured fields(Assume there is not any typo in case found).

```
personDoc | only index specified fields
a.  name | text | searchable as nameSort | keyword | index | store
b.  name | text | searchable as nameSearch | OCISSearchAnalyzer | index | include in _all field | include term vectors
c.  receivedDate | datetime | index
```

I want sort by name and then sort by receivedDate

```
new SearchQuery(String indexName, AbstractFtsQuery queryPart).fields("nameSort", "receivedDate").sort("nameSort", "receivedDate");
```

Here is full text index looks like:

```
...
"receivedDate": {
  "dynamic": false,
  "enabled": true,
  "fields": [
    {
      "analyzer": "keyword",
      "include_in_all": false,
      "include_term_vectors": true,
      "index": true,
      "name": "receivedDate",
      "store": false,
      "type": "datetime"
    }
  ]
},
"name": {
  "dynamic": false,
  "enabled": true,
  "fields": [
    {
      "analyzer": "keyword",
      "include_in_all": false,
      "include_term_vectors": false,
      "index": true,
      "name": "nameSort",
      "store": true,
      "type": "text"
    },
    {
      "analyzer": "OCISSearchAnalyzer",
      "include_in_all": true,
      "include_term_vectors": true,
      "index": true,
      "name": "nameSearch",
      "store": false,
      "type": "text"
    }
  ]
}
...
```

Comment: Have you solved it already? Did you notice you have a typo in the sort? .sort("nameSort", "recivedDate"); --> .sort("nameSort", "receivedDate");

Comment: I can't copy paste my whole code. Plz assume there is not any typo.